# HTML not displaying correctly when inserted using jQuery.html()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table that carries out some AJAX actions, an returns an error if one is encountered.

I'm using JS to insert this error (which is a string), but because the string has HTML tags in it, it's being appended at the end of the JS element where I wish it to be inserted, as opposed to in the middle.

```
var debug_error = '<span class="debug-message hidden">'+table_obj.debug_string+'</span>',
    row =         $(id+' .row-debug'); // id is definded

row.html(debug_error);
```

For example, if `debug_string` was `<h3>Error</h3><p>Please define an email address</p>`, my results are -

```
<span class="debug-message hidden"> </span>
<h3>Error</h3>
<p>Please define an email address</p>
```

Yet if I remove the HTML tags, an use just `ErrorPlease define an email address`, it works as expected -

```
<span class="debug-message hidden">ErrorPlease define an email address</span>
```

Does any body know why this is happening? Thanks.

Comment: It's illegal to put a H3 in a span element.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is because it's not valid to put a block level element, such as `h3`, inside an inline element, such as `span`. Make the `span` into a `div` and it should work:

```
var debug_error = '<div class="debug-message hidden">' + table_obj.debug_string + '</div >',
    row = $(id + ' .row-debug'); // id is definded    
row.html(debug_error);
```

If needed, you can make the `div` appear inline (and thus behave like the `span` did) using CSS:

```
.debug-message {
    display: inline;
}
```

Comment: Bingo, that did the job. Thanks for sharing the knowledge.